# Sql Server Data Generation

Tags: testing

Could anybody reccommend an open source / free tool for generating data for a Sql Server database?

I am looking for something like Redgate's Sql Data Generator.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

It mostly depends on your needs, because there are lots of tools for that purpose – as shown in the answer from NinethSense.

Not sure if you’ve checked ApexSQL tools, because they offer [ApexSQL Generate](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_generate.aspx) – a test data generator for SQL Server databases.

Now, it is not open source, but it does feature a fully functional free trial – so you can check it out and see if it is suitable for your needs.

Hope I helped

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at these links:

1. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Data_Generator.aspx
2. http://databene.org/
3. [http://www.benjaminkeen.com/software/data_generator](http://www.benjaminkeen.com/software/data_generator/)/
4. http://www.generatedata.com/

Comment: Sorry if it hurts. I removed that link :). Be happy